# What are reasons for Unity3D's owners to force rich guys buying Pro version?

Tags: unity, licensing, support

Well, I have to say that Unity is a really nice thing that can save one a dozen of hours on coding (letting instantly work on gameplay). But what's the idea of [*forcing*](http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses.html)
 (EULA) any party, which made over 100k last fiscal year, to purchase Pro instead of using normal edition!?

It feels that this kind of licensing provides hidden benefits to rich guys over me, poor sloven, who can afford buying $3.5k license but obviously will not receive any additional cookies from it.

And, by the way, anyone estimated how much Unity's source + Playstation + Xbox license will cost?

Comment: There are additional benefits to buying Pro. For the second question, you can send the sales group an email to ask. They require you be approved to develop on those consoles before hand though, AFAIK. But, in short expensive. Unity would rather people only use the Source license when they really really need it.

Comment: Seriously? If you made over $100k using Unity you'd be upset by paying a small licensing fee? Incidentally, I don't know where you got $3.5k because that's over twice what it actually costs.

Comment: $3.5k is the cost of iOS Pro or Android Pro.

Comment: @Joe Wreschnig : No it isn't. [They even do the math for you.](https://store.unity3d.com/shop/)

Comment: Actually I checked that page before posting, I just assumed "$1500 + $400 + $1500" was the cost of iOS Pro. Somewhat confusingly, the middle one is not included - it's only $3k. I guess it's the cost of iOS Pro + an Asset Server license though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The guys at Unity are spending a lot of money doing R&D, as well as licensing 3rd party tech to include in their software.

The only reason it's *free* in the first place is that they want to get as many people using it as possible, so when the big boys (read: people who are actually making money doing this and can afford to actually buy software) are investigating tech to use, there's a large group of people who are experienced with using it and can recommend it to the people who have control of purse strings.  Plus they have a vested interest with their web plugin to have as many people developing games for it as possible, and most web games don't make a lot of money.

The concept is very similar to a lot of software that's "free for non-commercial use".  In this case, it's "free for insignificant commercial use".

Comment: well, the Pro version has at least two advantages for me to buy it: support for native plugins and video playback, and the fact of someone buying Pro is not so significant.. OK, if the idea behind $100k limit is to force real customer to pay for the product - it's understandable.

Comment: Pro also comes with profiling and external source control, as well as render surfaces (which is used for many post-processing effects).